# How to use Dapper with Dommel and FluentMap to Insert a record into a table that doesn't have an Key?

Tags: c#, dapper, .net-5, dapper-fluentmap, dommel

I'm creating a service in my API that uses [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) with [Dommel](https://github.com/henkmollema/Dommel) and [FluentMap](https://github.com/henkmollema/Dapper-FluentMap).
The database is Microsoft SQL Server.
I have an endpoint that needs to insert a record into an table that hasn't a key.
The table is described like in this entity below:

```
public class MyTable
{ 
    public int SomeProperty{ get; set; }
    public int AnotherProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

This table only have these two columns in database. Doesn't have a key.

I want to use Dapper with Dommel, if it is possible, to insert a record in this table.

I already have created the maps and registered them, everything is fine and works for others tables that have an Key. But this one doesn't.

Every time a call the Dommel `InsertAsync` method I ended up with this error message:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[4](https://dapper-tutorial.net/execute#example-execute-insert)
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find the key properties for type 'MyProject.Models.MyTable'.

A already know it is possible to use only Dapper and manual create the SQL query and [execute it](https://dapper-tutorial.net/execute#example-execute-insert) .

I'm asking if there is a solution with Dommel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you posted looks like a many-to-many table, in which case the PK is both ID columns. There's almost never any good reason to create a table without a primary key

Comment: Besides Dommel's landing page describes how to map one-to-one and one-to-many relations, especially if the columns match the naming conventions, eg `ClientId` for `Client`, `ApplciationId` for Application. `IdApplicativo` require explicit configuration. Many-to-Many [are unsupported](https://github.com/henkmollema/Dommel/issues/34)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Unfortunately the table is already used in production(kkkrying) and I can't change it's structure. I need to know if there is a way to insert a record into a table that hasn't a key. I did not create this model and the table, I'm only  working on it.

Comment: I just posted a link to a Dommel issue that explicitly says they won't support many-to-many relations. Dapper isn't an full-featured ORM like EF Core. It only deals with mapping SQL results to objects. It doesn't handle relations. What are you trying to do anyway? Why is writing the `INSERT` query such an issue?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The many to many relationship doesn't matter, I do not validate it. It could be whatever table without a Key. I want to insert a record into a table that hasn't a Key.

Comment: Why would there ever be a table without a key? That's a bug, plain and simple. Again and again there are **very** few cases where a table without a primary key would make sense. Those very rare cases deal with complex problems and require writing queries by hand and taking care of locking issues. This is definitely not such a case. Unless you want to return duplicate Client/Application pairs, your actual table *will* have a key.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I couldn't agree more with you, Unfortunately can't do code refactoring on this and I need to work with this structure exactly the way it is. The `INSERT` query is not a issue, actually it is my current solution. Just forget about the many-to-many relationship and lets discuss about if it is possible to insert a record using Dommel into a table that has not a Key. I didn't find a solution in Dommel docs and I'm curious about it's possibility. Just that.

Comment: That's not `just that`. ORMs require keys to know which rows to insert, update or delete. Dommel isn't a generic SQL generator, it's an ORM component that generates the proper SQL queries to persist objects. So it needs keys. Besides, your table **does have keys**.

Comment: I edited the question to remove the many-to-many relationship out of discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a key. ORMs require keys so they know which row to insert, delete or update. It's simply impossible for an ORM to work without keys. Dommel isn't a SQL generator, it works with Dapper so it *needs* keys.

The class does have keys anyway - that's a many-to-many table with a composite key. Dommel recognizes the `Key` attribute which can be used to specify composite keys.

In Dommel's unit test the [ProductsCategories class](https://github.com/henkmollema/Dommel/blob/be5610153c1069029de5f9bd3e99e21ba8d30c80/test/Dommel.IntegrationTests/GetTests.cs#L113) is used to represent a many-to-many relation with a composite key:

```
public class ProductsCategories
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So, the answer to the question is: No, you need to use keys, there is no way to use Dommel. I will stick with my query solution mentioned in the question.